# Passing C struct elements to C++ dll library function

Tags: c++, c, dll, struct

I am trying to use a functions from a C++ dll library calling it from a C interface (lite-C), but I have problem passing structure elements to the called dll function.

The dll library contains several functions. It is a C++ library with a C-API (compiled with EXTERN C and def file).

For example, I declare and initialise the required dll function prototype in my C header:

```
const char* __cdecl foo(const svm_problem *prob, const svm_parameter *param);
```

`prob` and `param` are two structs with several elements. I declare them in my C header exactly as they are in the C++ header used to build the dll.

Then I initialize the struct in my C code and pass pointers on them to the foo function.

I am able to call the dll `foo` function in the main script, however the foo function seems not to recognize some struct components (variables) passed through the function argument as a pointer, and so doesn’t work properly.

For example when I initialize, let say param.C to 1.0  and call `foo(&prob, &param)` the functions returns me an error: `C<=0`.

However when I check param.C by printing its content in a message it gives me 1.0, which is correct.

Somehow its value is not passed properly to the dll function (its type is double).

However, other elements of the same struct are passed correctly to foo.

Strangely, for another member of the same struct, of type double I had the same problem till I declared this element as float instead of double in my C header, but a double is declared in the dll and expected in the foo function.

I also tried to initialize my struct as global, but this doesn’t change anything.

Does anyone have any idea how to make this work?

Here are the structs:

```
    struct svm_problem
{
 int l;
 double *y;
 struct svm_node **x;
};

struct svm_parameter
{
 int svm_type;
 int kernel_type;
 int degree;
 double gamma;
 double coef0;
 double cache_size;
 double eps;
 double C;
 int nr_weight;
 int *weight_label;
 double* weight;
 double nu;
 double p;
 int shrinking;
 int probability;
};
```

Comment: Don't have two struct definitions. Have one in the C header only. Include it in the C++ code.

Comment: Show the struct. Are you violating the one definition rule? Maybe one of the struct members is different depending on the includes before it? Did you print and compare the address of the struct in the caller and the callee? Are both working on the same address?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. 1) to build the dll it needs the header with declared structured otherwise it refuse to generate the dll. And to run the lite-C code it need also to have the struct defined and initialised, for being able to pass the pointer to it. I don't now how to  make only one definition. Maybe not in the c++ header but inside the called function, to make it local?

Comment: Do you use the same packing/alignment for the structs in the caller and callee modules?

Comment: Yes, I rechecked the packing/alignement for being identical.

Comment: By checking the adresses of the param struct in the caller and the callee they are indeed different.

Comment: @Nello _"I don't now how to make only one definition. "_ In a header file as usual?

Comment: @Nello: Does sizeof(<insert struct name here>) give the same result in caller and callee? Does sizeof(<pointer to struct>)?

Comment: @Cwan: sizof for pointer are identical (4) in both the caller and callee, but sizeof struct are different (58 for the caller, 96 for the callee).

Comment: The first 3 param elements are passed correctly, then no more from gamma.

Comment: The param adress is 01BC9EC8 in the caller and 01BC9EA0 in the callee.

Comment: A size of 56 bytes for the svm_parameter struct seems far too small, assuming 32-bit ints, 32-bit pointers and 64-bit doubles. I just read that lite-C always pack structs to one-byte alignment, but the size still seems way to small. The size on the C++ side seems reasonable, but it looks like it's not really packed to one-byte alignment. All that assuming that you are showing us the exact definition of the structs and my assumptions on data sizes are correct.

Comment: My mistake i printf the sizeof with wrong format. Lite-C struct is 88 bytes which is exactly what is expected. 96 for the C++ dll. Looking at the respective struct adresses, somehow C++ reallocate the struct 28 bytes earlier in the memory.

Comment: Focus on the difference in sizes. If you haven't already, find the C++ compiler pragmas to control packing (e.g. #pragma pack for VC++). Use that to control packing for all your shared structs. Also ensure to save/restore current packing before/after the struct definitions.

Comment: #pragma pack seems to make things work (same struct size) and correct values passed, but the pointer address is still different in lite-C and C++. Is this acceptable? Thank you so much for you help.

Comment: I really can't tell if it's acceptable. I would expect the same address, but it's possible that lite-C adjusts or indirects addresses from their actual location for some reason, but that's pure speculation. Fill both structs with unique values for each member and make sure that they are the same after crossing the call boundary - should be sufficient for verification. Perhaps you could post a question in the lite-C forums?

Comment: Thank you Cwan. I am indeed doing  some checking as you mention within the dll. The values are the same after crossing the call boundary. I keep investigating.

Comment: My mistake again (I am still a newbie in prog...). Both addresses in Lite-C and in the Dll are the same. I was comparing pointer value in Lite-C with pointer adress in the dll...

Comment: Thanks for your great support !